# How to show repeated row one time mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is [image: Data base]

I want to show rows with same stop name one time..

How i use Query and While Loop

Comment: `select * from table order by stop`

Comment: Its repeating...

Comment: `select * from table group by stop`

Answer (score 0):

I see you have and `id` column. Assuming that it is unique you can do this all in sql query, no need for while loop.

You will need 2 queries; first will get the maximum (could be minimum also) available id of only one distinct stop name, the second is a join query with the first results and the main table. Something like this:

```
select * from tablename
inner join 
(
select stop, max(id) as id from tablename
group by stop
) 
as uniqueIDs
on tablename.id=uniqueIDs.id
```

Answer (score 0):

u may try this..this will help you to fetch duplicates from table

```
SELECT  tablename.stop FROM tablename INNER JOIN 
(SELECT stop FROM   tablename GROUP  BY stop HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
ON tablename.stop = dup.stop;
```